# Firebase rules enable only for one node

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Realtime Database and would like to set a rule only for one node ("Devices/{number}"). For all other paths I would like for the rules to stay read, write: true.

This is what I tried:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Devices": {
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    },
  }
}
```

However this doesn't achieve what I want because it doesn't allow write/read on any other path.
And if I try this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Devices": {
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    },
  }
}
```

Then the rule under devices does nothing and you can delete data under devices.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [wildcard rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables), like this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Devices": {
      ".write": "!data.exists()"
    },
    "$other": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
  }
}
```

This applies the `!data.exists()` rule to `Devices` and `true` to all other top-level nodes.

---

If you want to allow users to only add a specific device under `Devices`, and not replace the entire node, you should use a wildcard for that too:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Devices": {
      "$deviceId": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    },
    "$other": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
  }
}
```